# Replicate collection of objects as particles, but keeping their original relative orientation

Tags: particles

I'd like to replicate a collection of objects as particles on a surface, but keeping their original relative orientation.

Imagine two people side by side. I want to replicate them together as a pair all over an object. However, when I do particles by collection, it splits the people up and randomly distributes the individuals -- and not the pairs -- over the surface describable

My issue is that I've got some text that needs to stay close by its associated object. I can create the collection as particles, but then it randomizes where everything is and therefore the object particles no longer have labels nearby.

I think to join them to one object would generally work but one of my objects is a text, which I can't seem to join.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: please us screenshots of what you have and what you like to have. 3 sentences for describing a problem in Blender is nearly never enough. And what helps too: provide your blend file

Comment: It's blending right now, but I think I can describe my issue. Imagine two people side by side. I want to replicate them together as a pair all over an object. However, when I do particles by collection, it splits the people up and randomly distributes the individuals -- and not the pairs -- over the surface describable.

Comment: why don't you just join them to one object?

Comment: I think that would generally work but one of my objects is a text, which I can't seem to join.

Comment: You can only join meshes. Just convert your text to mesh, then you can join.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Is there a way to mark your comment as a solution?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Ask @Chris to post an answer then you can accept it. Comments are there to clarify things and ask for more info. All info should be in your question at a glance. If you have more info please feel free to edit your question and add it so readers have an overview. Comments can be deleted every time and only the first 6 or 8 are displayed. Then you have to click "more" to see them all. Readers can miss important info if it's only in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Geometry Nodes, you can instance objects which are, themselves, [Collection Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/collection.html). So you can make your pairs-of-people Collection Instances.

Here, Point Distribute is aimed at the collection 'CC'.

[image]

'CC' contains a curve, a couple of meshes, and a couple of collection instances, 'C1' and 'C2', made of a cylinder and a doughnut or 2:

[image]

Comment: +1 for naming the pyramid Cube. Love it!!!!!!

Comment: @Chris  Spotted! LMAO :D !! The pyramid refuses to disavow its ancestry :)

Comment: Suggest using Doughnuts & Anvils.

Comment: @batFINGER Damn. Of course. Default collection instance from here on. :)

Comment: could be new  lyrics for the [tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Favorite_Things_(song)) done [_Weird Robin Bettsovich_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic) style.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily join the objects by selecting them and then press CTRL-J.
You can convert text to mesh via the menu: object -> convert to mesh.
After that you can join the „text as mesh“ too.

Comment: @batFINGER : ok, only of same Type?he wrote in comments about text…

Comment: @batFINGER I could be wrong, but I couldn't get a Particle System to render collection instances from inside a referenced collection. Geonodes do it, though.

Comment: NP It'd be me that's wrong, was under an untested impression.